# Pythonで2次元リストの条件に合う要素を抽出

Tags: python

2つ以上同一の要素を含むリストを抽出したいです．

具体的には

```
li=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

liは，[1,2,3]が2つ，[2,3,4]が3つ，[3,4,5][4,5,6][5,6,7]は1つずつ含まれており，
2つ以上同一の要素を含むリストを抽出し，以下のli2のような結果を求めたいです．

```
li2=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Python3で動く例です。

```
li=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(map(tuple, li))
```

最終的にli2の要素がリストでなくてもいいなら:

```
li2 = list(filter(lambda x: c[x] > 1, c))
```

リストじゃなきゃダメなら:

```
li2 = list(map(list, filter(lambda x: c[x] > 1, c)))
```

もし順序も維持したいなら:

```
li2 = sorted(list(map(list, filter(lambda x: c[x] > 1, c))), key=li.index)
```

Comment: 丁寧な解答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 順序の維持はこれが正しいやり方ですね。

Answer (score 0):

**方法1**
`itertools.groupby`を使う方法。ソートして同じ要素が並んだ時はグループ化します。結果の順序は維持されません。

```
from itertools import groupby
print [k for k, g in groupby(sorted(li)) if len(list(g)) >= 2]
```

**方法2**
`collections.Counter`を使う方法。結果の順序は維持されません。

```
import collections

li=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
li2 = map(lambda (k,v): list(k), # タプルの部分だけ取り出して、リストに戻す
          filter(lambda (x, v): v>= 2, # Counterで数えた結果で2個以上を抽出
                 collections.Counter(
                     map(tuple, li)  # Counterで数えられるようにハッシュ可能なタプルにする
                 ).items()
          )
)
print li2
```

実行結果

```
[[2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: 迅速な解答ありがとうございます．参考になりました．

Answer (score 0):

すでに回答になっているのですが、mapやlambdaよりList Comprehensionの方がすっきりする気がします。

```
from collections import Counter
li=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[2,3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
c = Counter(tuple(items) for items in li)
more_than_one = [items for items, count in c.most_common() if count > 1]
```

more_than_one：

> [(2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3)]